# Meaning of $X(B_1)$ where X is a random variable

Tags: random-variables, set-partition

I'm studying the formal definition a [Dirichlet process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process):
$${if } X \sim \operatorname{DP}(H,\alpha)$$ 
$$\text{then }(X(B_1),\dots,X(B_n)) \sim \operatorname{Dir}(\alpha H(B_1),\dots, \alpha H(B_n))$$

where $$B_1,...,B_n \text{ are the partitions of a measurable set S} $$

What does $X(B_n)$ mean? Could you provide me an example?

I can't really see what does notation represents.
Hitherto I have always seen random variables such $X$ "on their own"  and the notation $X(B_n)$ really confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  the article you have quoted it says : a Dirichlet process is a probability distribution whose range is itself a set of probability distributions. For each sample point $\omega$, $X(\omega)$ is not a number but a probability measure. $X(B)$ is defined by $X(B)(\omega)=X(\omega) (B)$, the measure of $B$ under $X(\omega)$. For example, you can have something like $X(\omega) (B)=\int_B \phi(\omega,t) dt$. If you fix $B$ you have an ordinary random variable and if you fix $\omega$ you get a measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu (B)=\int_B \phi(\omega,t) dt$.

An example: let $\{W_t\}$ be standard Brownian motion. Define $X(\omega) ([a,b))=W_b(\omega)-W_a (\omega)$. You can extend this to $X(\omega) (A)$ when $A$ is a finite union of half closed intervals. Using some standard techniques you can extend this to $X(\omega) (A)$ for any Borel set $A$. It is customary to write $X(A)(\omega)$ for $X(\omega) (A)$.

Comment: Thank for answering, but it's still not clear. Particularly, in this contest what is a sample point $\omega$? Is it a point from the measurable set S? Furthermore what is $\phi(\omega,t)$ ?

Comment: There is basic probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ on which $X$ is defined. A sample point is simply an element of $\Omega$. In my example $\phi$ could be any measurable function on $\Omega \times \mathbb R$ such that it is integrable w.r.t. Lebesgue measure for every $\omega$.

Comment: And how is this probability space related to the measurable set S and its partitions? What is the sample space $\Omega$ of this probability space? I can't visualize it.

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli $X(\omega)$ is a measure on some set $S$ with a sigma algebra. In my example it is the real line with Borel sigma algebra. $\Omega$ and $S$ are not related in general.

Comment: I've seen what you added and it's clearer now.  B is an area, and different $\omega$ lead to the different measurement of B. The sum all measurements of B has any constraints? Does it have to sum to 1 or is the probability of all $\omega$ that has to sum to 1?